# Windows 10, VS2015 System.UnauthorizedAccessException issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I am using VS2015 under Win10.

I have an old application which just been brought onto this platform. I need to open a serial port inside the application. Here is the code segment

```
_port = new SerialPort (port, 19200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
_port.DtrEnable = false;
_port.Handshake = Handshake.None;
_port.RtsEnable = false;
_port.ReadTimeout = 150;
_port.WriteTimeout = 150;

try {
    _port.Open ();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    TryTrace (TraceEventType.Error, 0, 
              String.Format("Exception opening port: {0}", e.Message));
    throw;
}
```

This throw exception `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`, Access denied.

I open this application by using run as administrator.

I then created a test application, only try to open the same serial port. which works perfect.

I have tried to switch of UAC,it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Does anybody got idea?

Thanks very much

Comment: You mention that you've tried to switching off UAC. Did you re-launch VS when you did that? Also have you tried running VS as an administrative user and seeing what happens? Messing with COM port settings (as opposed to using them) sounds like a task that would require elevation...